# Using multiple GPUs in tensorflow 2.2 with tensorflow_hub

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp, gpu, tensorflow-hub

I'm trying to pre-process a huge text array ( around 1.2M phrases) using Google's Universal Sentence Encoder and get the (n,512) dimension numpy array.

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os, logging
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'

import glob
import gc

import tensorflow as  tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub

print(tf.__version__,hub.__version__,tf.keras.__version__)
print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')))

['/device:CPU:0', '/device:XLA_CPU:0', '/device:XLA_GPU:0', '/device:XLA_GPU:1', '/device:GPU:0', '/device:GPU:1']
Num GPUs Available:  2

module_obj = 'https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-large/5'
use_embed =   hub.load(module_obj)

def preprocessDf(tmp):
    df_text_raw = tmp['description'].tolist()  ## description column to a list
    return (df_text_raw)

def getEmbed(df):
    xtrain1 = preprocessDf(df)
    tmp_embed = use_embed(xtrain1).numpy()
    return(tmp_embed)

df_train.shape
(1218741, 2)

df_train_split = np.array.split(df_train, 200)  ## Split the 1.2M rows dataframe into 200 parts

xtrain_embed =  np.empty((0,512), float)

for i,tmp in enumerate(df_train_split):
    print("Doing chunk: ",i+1)
    use_embed =   hub.load(module_obj)
    xtrain_embed = np.concatenate([xtrain_embed, getEmbed(tmp)], axis = 0)
    print(xtrain_embed.shape)

df_train_split[0].shape
(6094, 2)


df_train_split['description'].sample(5)

5170367    nike nike free metcon 1 69 99                                                      
4477058    ebay sol de oro liquid brillantine for gray hair brillantina lquida para las 1 9 99
1337259    poshmark club monaco coat xs 1 150                                                 
1001626    nordstrom faux shearling faux suede vest regular petite 1 19 97                    
76780      etsy sunflower dangle 1 4 8
```

After processing about 19 chunks, I run into out of memory error (OOM) error and I have 2 GPUs, but only 1 is being used.

```
ResourceExhaustedError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Resource exhausted:  OOM when allocating tensor with shape[6094,8,196,196] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
     [[{{node StatefulPartitionedCall/StatefulPartitionedCall/EncoderTransformer/Transformer/SparseTransformerEncode/Layer_0/SelfAttention/SparseMultiheadAttention/DotProductAttention/MatMul}}]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.

     [[StatefulPartitionedCall/StatefulPartitionedCall/EncoderTransformer/Transformer/layer_prepostprocess/layer_norm/add_1/_268]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.

  (1) Resource exhausted:  OOM when allocating tensor with shape[6094,8,196,196] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
     [[{{node StatefulPartitionedCall/StatefulPartitionedCall/EncoderTransformer/Transformer/SparseTransformerEncode/Layer_0/SelfAttention/SparseMultiheadAttention/DotProductAttention/MatMul}}]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.

0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored. [Op:__inference_restored_function_body_4341335]

Function call stack:
restored_function_body -> restored_function_body
```

1. How can I make sure both the GPUs are being used while running the use_embed object.
2. Any other ways of using both GPUs and avoiding the OOM error.

I have tried this :

```
mirrored_strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy()
with mirrored_strategy.scope():
    use_embed =   hub.load(module_obj)
```

but it gives me an error:

```
INFO:tensorflow:Using MirroredStrategy with devices ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0', '/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:1')
INFO:tensorflow:Using MirroredStrategy with devices ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0', '/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:1')

InvalidArgumentError:  assertion failed: [Trying to access a placeholder that is not supposed to be executed. This means you are executing a graph generated from the cross-replica context in an in-replica context.]
     [[node Assert/Assert (defined at /home/xxxx/miniconda3/envs/tf2-gpu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow_hub/module_v2.py:102) ]] [Op:__inference_restored_function_body_4258999]

Function call stack:
restored_function_body
```

nvidia-smi output ( Only GPU 0 is being used)

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 418.67       Driver Version: 418.67       CUDA Version: 10.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla P100-SXM2...  Off  | 00000000:5E:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   42C    P0    43W / 300W |  15463MiB / 16280MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  Tesla P100-SXM2...  Off  | 00000000:86:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   40C    P0    41W / 300W |    265MiB / 16280MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0     61232      C   ...srta/miniconda3/envs/tf2-gpu/bin/python 15453MiB |
|    1     61232      C   ...srta/miniconda3/envs/tf2-gpu/bin/python   255MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: With Mirrrored strategy, you were getting that error because you might be using the older USE models converted from TF1 to TF2([refer here](https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/issues/515#issuecomment-656800105)), Can you try using any of the models in this [comment](https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/issues/515#issuecomment-776912796) and see if it works fine with MirroredStrategy, enabling you to use multiple GPUs? Thanks!